# TFS Merge creates changese to merge back

Tags: tfs, merge

I would ask you if you have some experiences with merge by tf.exe. I have two branches - branch 1 and child branch branch 2 created from branch 1. I have some changesets in branch 2 and I want to merge it to branch 1 (reverse integration). I merge it by tf.exe (my external tool call it). Then I want to show merge candidate from branch 1 to branch 2 (forward integration) and there are changesets created by previous merge from branch 2 to branch 1.

I compare branch 2 and branch 1 after merge from branch 2 to branch 1 and there are no differences. But I have still changesets in branch 1 which want to merge brachn 2. When I would merge these changesets from branch 1 to branch 2 (forward) then there are conflicts in resx files.

When I merge these changesets from branch 2 to branch 1 by Visual Studio there are not changesets to merge from branch 1 to branch 2.

What is different? I use my external merge tool because of create some reports of merged changesets and some reason of planning and releasing.

I found some related topics but there was about renaming of branches. But I have stable naming branches. Problem is when I do forward integration because this changesets do problems in merge.

Comment: I investigated it and problem is when revers integration is made there are some changes (encoding and another changes) in merged changeset.

Comment: Hi Zefek, did you mean the issue have fixed? `When I merge these changesets from branch 2 to branch 1 by Visual Studio there are not changesets to merge from branch 1 to branch 2.` This seems make sense, there are some specific changesets only located at branch2 .

Comment: I must have some tool because of release management. When I merged by tool from dev branch to main (trunk) branch there were some changesets in main branch to merge into dev branch which was created by merge from dev to main.
When I investigated it there were only changesets with xml files (resx, and some xml files) which have different encoding. I can expand merged changeset in main branch I can see changeset merged from and I compare these two chanageset and there was different encoding. 
So I will see in next merge if it is fixed but I hope it.

Comment: Exactly say problem is not in tf.exe. Problem is merge tool settings using for resolve conflicts. I use kdiff and there was another encoding for output file.